# How to remove the watermark?

Tags: php

Can you please show me how to get rid of the watermark part so that the function only resizes images not watermark on it?

```
$path = "logo.png";
function watermark_image_post($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    global $path ;
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = 720; $height = 450;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($path );
    list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($path );        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
    imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks alot

Comment: it depend on the image, Is the water mark part of the image or it's something your code is adding to it ?

Comment: The above function currently adds  logo.png on top of every uploaded images, i wish to get rid of it from the function.

Comment: I'd say remove the usage of the variable  `watermark` and check where it brings you.

Comment: I did try but then you know at times some images turns out pure black, could you show the right way to get rid of it?

Comment: If you just want to resize an image and don't need all of this watermark thing, you could simply start over, in a different function. I'm sure there is a millions tutorial online on how to resize image in php. You resize your image and THEN you add the watermark.

Comment: There sure will be but i needed help with this particular function, so i need your expert help if you could? would appreciate it

Comment: I'm no expert, unfortunately. I'm trying my best to help each and everyone from the little i know about many things. As for you problem, i'm quite out of idea. Sorry.

Comment: Just comment out the line that starts `imagecopy(`, that seems to be the one that actually copies the watermark onto the image. All the line starting from `$watermark = ` and ending at `imagecopy(` are handling the watermark, and could all be removed, but the last one is the line that actually places it in the image.

Comment: @droopsnoot is this the right way?/////

function watermark_image_post($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){

    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = 720; $height = 450;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;    
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}

Comment: @droopsnoot if you have the time could you show me the perfect way to do it? as i at times get black images too uploaded by users

Comment: Sorry, I can offer no explanation for that. Does it happen to certain images - that is, if you upload the same image more than once, does it always go black, or only sometimes?